# pcap / winpcap - send packet to Rx

Tags: winapi, networking, pcap, libpcap, winpcap

I'm capturing traffic with winpcap on a Windows machine that is also a network gateway, so I see packets with src mac, src ip, dst mac, and dst ip which are different from the gateway's mac and ip.

What I'm trying to do is redirect some of those packets to a listening server (for example, redirect all port 80 HTTP packets to a local HTTP server instead of their original destination, something similar to a captive portal).

My idea is to disable IP forwarding on the gateway so packets won't go out, and reinject the captured packets to the interface again with winpcap.  However, the listening server ignores these packets.

I researched this issue, and found out that maybe it has something to do with Rx, Tx. Apparently, when you send packets with winpcap, listening for those packets on the same interface won't work because listening is on the Rx channel and sending is on the Tx channel.

Does anyone know any workaround for this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. Do you want to capture again the packets you've reinjected?

Comment: @pchaigno yes, so the listening server would catch them

Comment: So the packets have the correct address (local) and port (that of the listening server)?

Comment: @pchaigno yes, I also corrected the checksums so Wireshark says they're OK. However the server ignores those packets

Comment: Do you see them on the loopback interface? Is the MAC correct?

Comment: It would really help if you could post a minimal reproduction example...